# Azure cosmos db continuation token not working with WHERE

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a collection of lubes. A lube can either be available or out-of-stock. I would like to query max of 5 lubes at a time.

When I'm not using a filter, the continuation token is returned and works fine.

```
// <Get all lubes / first page (max: 5) >
  async getAll(token?: string, limit = 5) {
    if (!token) this.store.lube.removeAll();
    const {
      resources: items,
      continuationToken,
      hasMoreResults,
    } = await this.dbContainer.items
      .readAll<ILube>({
        maxItemCount: limit,
        continuationToken: token,
        // partitionKey: "HFO",
      })
      .fetchNext();
    this.store.lube.load(items);
    return { hasMoreResults, continuationToken };
  }
```

However, when I want to filter by available lubes, or out-of-stock, using **`WHERE`**, the continuation token is returned, however, when I retrieved the data, it doesn't work - no error.

```
// <Get by availability status>
  async getByAvailability(availability: boolean, token?: string, limit = 5) {
    if (!token) this.store.lube.removeAll();
    this.store.lube.removeAll();
    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.isAvailable = @availability",
      parameters: [
        {
          name: "@availability",
          value: availability,
        },
      ],
    };
    const {
      resources: items,
      continuationToken,
      hasMoreResults,
    } = await this.dbContainer.items
      .query<ILube>(querySpec, { maxItemCount: limit })
      .fetchNext();
    this.store.lube.load(items);
    return { hasMoreResults, continuationToken };
  }
```

Bottom line, how can I use `continuation token` with `where`?

Comment: Please see this thread on Twitter: https://twitter.com/gmantri/status/1434551588966731791. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the code. Continuation token can be used with `WHERE`.

**Mistake 1**: I didn't include the `continuationToken` in the query of `getByAvailability`

**Mistake 2**: I removed the items from the store even when the **`token!=null`**.

```
this.store.lube.removeAll();

// <Get by availability status>
  async getByAvailability(availability: boolean, token?: string, limit = 5) {
    if (!token) this.store.lube.removeAll();


    // **Mistake 2** 
    // this.store.lube.removeAll(); // This line is not needed.

    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.isAvailable = @availability",
      parameters: [
        {
          name: "@availability",
          value: availability,
        },
      ],
    };


   **Mistake 1: Query didn't have continuationToken in it, only had the one being returned.**
    
    const {
      resources: items,
      continuationToken,
      hasMoreResults,
    } = await this.dbContainer.items
      .query<ILube>(querySpec, { maxItemCount: limit, continuationToken: token })
      .fetchNext();
    this.store.lube.load(items);
    return { hasMoreResults, continuationToken };
  }
```